# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.index.BaseIndex

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, ignite

I had updated the version of H2 Database Engine from **1.4.195** to **2.1.210**.
Now when I try to run the spring boot application I'm getting error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/index/BaseIndex
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.inClassPath(IgniteUtils.java:1727)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.inClassPath(IgniteComponentType.java:160)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.initializeDefaultSpi(IgnitionEx.java:2480)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.initializeConfiguration(IgnitionEx.java:2328)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1697)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1117)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:637)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:563)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:321)
    at com.x.y.z.cache.ignite.IgniteCacheProviderWithExpiry.init(IgniteCacheProviderWithExpiry.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    ... 60 more
```

Please help me in solving the issue.

Comment: What's the complete stack trace of the failure? It should show what code is referring to H2's `BaseIndex` class.

Comment: I had added the complete stack trace of the failure. It's due to ignite

Comment: What version of Apache Ignite do you use? For example, 2.12.0 requires H2 1.4.197 and cannot be used with new versions of H2.

Comment: Thanks now I got it. Can you share some resource where it's mentioned. It'll be very helpful for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache Ignite uses unsupported internal classes of H2 Database instead of own code or some proper third-party library, they aren't a part of API and can be modified in any way in every release of H2. You can find the required version in `pom.xml` of `ignite-core`. For Apache Ignite 2.12.0 it is H2 1.4.197: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-core/2.12.0/ignite-core-2.12.0.pom and this version is unlikely to be updated, Ignite / GridGain and H2 parted the ways a long time ago.

Apache Ignite project has some plans to use Apache Calcite as SQL engine in future versions of Apache Ignite: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/Apache+Calcite-powered+SQL+Engine+Roadmap